# Google form add createChoice if not null or empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to add some values to google forms which available on the sheets. My script looks like,

```
for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){

    if (myShuffled[i][0] == myAnswers[i][0]) {

      var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();

      addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0])

      .setPoints(1)

      .setChoices([
       
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][0],true),
         
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][1]),

        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][2]),

        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][3]),

        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][4]),
         
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][5]),
         
        addItem.createChoice(myShuffled[i][6])

      ]);

    }
....
....
```

For example I need to add `myShuffled[i][1]` only if not null or empty.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and current situation as follows.

- You want to put `addItem.createChoice` when `myShuffled[i][#]` is both not `null` and not empty.
- In your current issue, when `myShuffled[i][#]` is not `null` or not empty, the empty choice is put.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I would like to propose to create the choice values for putting to `addMultipleChoiceItem()` before `setChoices` is run.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberRows; i++) {
  if (myShuffled[i][0] == myAnswers[i][0]) {
    var addItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    var values = myShuffled[i].reduce((ar, e, i) => {
      if (e != null && e != "") ar.push(addItem.createChoice(e, ar.length == 0 ? true : false));
      return ar;
    }, []);
    addItem.setTitle(myQuestions[i][0]).setPoints(1).setChoices(values);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, please use the script by enabling V8 runtime.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)